# functools.partial as IronPython EventHandler

Tags: python, ironpython, eventhandler

I'm currently trying out the `IronPython` interpreter. While doing the Tutorial i came across delegates and event handlers. The tutorial does something like this:

```
from System.IO import FileSystemWatcher

w = FileSystemWatcher()

def handle(*args):
    print args

w.Changed += handle
```

So i tried to be smart and do this:

```
from System.IO import FileSystemWatcher
from __future__ import print_function
from functools import partial    

w = FileSystemWatcher()
w.Changed += partial(print, "Changed: ")
```

Which failed with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Object is not callable.
```

Where `line 1` refers to the last line in the (interactive session)

So IronPython thinks a `partial` object is not callable although `callable(partial(print, "Changed: "))` returns `True`

With this workaround the handler is accepted:

```
w.Changed += partial(print, "Changed: ").__call__
```

My question:

Why is a `partial` object not accepted as an event handler. Is this a bug?

Comment: Sounds like lambdas or actual function may be used as event handlers, not arbitrary (callable) objects. I wouldn't call that a bug, more of an unfortunate incompatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not solution, one could expect, but there is an issue, opened for couple years now - https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/issues/808

> Doesn't work in 2.6.2 and 2.7b1 on .NET Version: 4.0.30319.1 ipy26
>   testcase-26482.py
>
> Object is not callable.
>
> ipy27 testcase-26482.py
>
> Object is not callable.py
>
> testcase-26482.py
>
> Object is not callable.